# automation errors in Flex Builder 3 when importing a swc from Flash CS 5

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, flex4, flash-cs5, swc

I am facing a really weird issue while trying to use an "swc" file imported from Flash CS5, that I am trying to use in Flex Builder 3 (by converting symbol to "Flex Component"). The errors are coming in files which are not even remotely related to the "swc" file that i am importing.

Now, I know that the automation stuff has come as a part of FB4, but I don't really have an option to migrate to FB4.

I have tried to change the flex sdk settings in Flash CS5 (steps given below), but that has not helped.
Edit-->Preferences-->Actionscript-->"Actionscript 3.0 Settings"-->"Flex SDK Path" (pointing this to flex3.5 sdk instead of Flex4.0 sdk)

I feel that the issue is most probably a compatibility issue b/w Flex 3 and Flex 4, but have not been able to find a workaround for the same. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kapil

Here is the trace:

```
Severity and Description    Path    Resource    Location    Creation Time   Id
1044: Interface method createAutomationIDPartWithRequiredProperties in namespace mx.automation:IAutomationObject not implemented by class com.sparsha.view.ui:SchematicWindow.
1044: Interface method createAutomationIDPartWithRequiredProperties in namespace mx.automation:IAutomationObject not implemented by class 
1044: Interface method get automationEnabled in namespace mx.automation:IAutomationObject not implemented by class com.sparsha.lib.controls:CloseableTabBar.    
1044: Interface method get automationEnabled in namespace mx.automation:IAutomationObject not implemented by class 
1044: Interface method get automationEnabled in namespace mx.automation:IAutomationObject not implemented by class com.sparsha.lib.layouts:DockedAppLayout.
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, first, the error: this means that Flash probably generated a class for the symbol you are importing using a certain template, where the template doesn't fit the SDK you are using to compile the project. Specifically, the generated class did not implement the methods listed in the error message. I.e. your framework.swc has a definition of mx.automation:IAutomationObject that has method createAutomationIDPartWithRequiredProperties() (nice name btw), but Flash generated code that reads as

```
package com.sparsha.view.ui {
import mx.automation:IAutomationObject;
public class SchematicWindow implements IAutomationObject { . . . } }
```

Since you cannot do anything about Flash not generating the method you need, your only way is to monkeypatch the SDK. I.e. copy the mx/automation/IAutomationObject.as from the SDK sources to the classpath of your project. Remove the conflicting method declaration (this may or may not result in other errors). If it results in further errors, repeat the same procedure for every class that "misbehaves"...

However, monkeypatching will mean that you are no longer able to use framework RSLs, as they will come with the original version. So, I would try to avoid the problem altogether and look for another way of exporting symbols from Flash IDE, for example, by not making them a Flex component. Or, if you really insist on them being a Flex component, then bootstrap the FlexSprite, for example, and assign your Flash symbols the bootstrapped class as the "parent class".

Comment: Hi Wvxw....thanks for your response. We finally managed to bypass the problem by creating the swc files from Adobe CS4.....also we are migrating to FB4 now....so hopefully this will not be an issue !!

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this problem recently.  I would get the errors when I included the flash generated swc in my flex projects lib folder.

I was able to work around the issue by upgrading my flex to the flex 4.5.1.21328A SDK.

Additional Details about my project that might help others:
My swc was generated from Flash Professional CS5.5 and my Flex Project was being used in Flash Builder 4.5.

My swc was published to Flash Player 9 with ActionScript 3.0.
My flex project was using the 3.5.0.12683 SDK.